# How to find index of item with shortest list inside?

Tags: python, list

So I have a list in this format:

```
lst = [[x1, y1, [1,3,4]], [x2, y2, [6,3]], [x3, y3, [8,6,3,9]]]
```

I want to find the index of item with the **shortest list inside**.
i.e. In this case it would return `[x2, y2, [6,3]]` since `[6,3]` is the shortest list in this case.

Of course I can iterate through to find the shortest item but is there better/faster way to do this in python?

Comment: *Of course I can iterate through to find the shortest item but is there better/faster way to do this in python?* Nope.

Comment: What do you mean by "index"?  You say index but your expected result is the item.

Comment: @jedwards There is just a more elegant way using `min` :).

Comment: Sure, I agree there are nice ways to do it -- but they all will boil down to iterating through the list -- whether explicitly iterating or using a function that iterates for you.

Comment: Do you know before hand how many levels deep your list can be or is it dynamic?

Comment: @user3885927 It will always be as displayed in the example above. It will not get any deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), providing a key function that returns the length of the sublist:

```
min(lst, key=lambda item: len(item[2]))
```

Note that iteration over `lst` still takes place implicitly when using `min`.  There is no other way to check every item than to iterate.

If you really need the index do:

```
index = min(range(len(lst)), key=lambda dx: len(lst[dx][2])
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this assumes that the "sublist" is always in the last position of each element.

Comment: @jedwards It will always be the case for this purpose.

Comment: @sPaz then this will be perfect -- and the edit to find the index (if that is indeed what you want) is more efficient than approaches listed in other answers.

Comment: py2x? range will create a list which you do not need

Comment: @akaRem:  That's true if using Python 2.x.  If using Python 2.x replace `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Unfortunately I don't know people who use py3k on prod :(

Answer (score 2):

```
In [33]: lst = [['x1', 'y1', [1,3,4]], ['x2', 'y2', [6,3]], ['x3', 'y3', [8,6,3,9]]]

In [34]: min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda t : min(len(s) for s in t[1] if isinstance(s,list)))[0]
Out[34]: 1
```

Comment: `enumerate(L)` gives me a list of each element in `L`, prefixed with its index. Thus `t[1]` is the element in `L` itself

Comment: ah, ok, didn't see enumerate

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is:

```
min(lst, key=lambda x: len(x[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If inner list is always the last one item

```
from itertools import imap

your_min = min(imap(len, (item[-1] for item in your_list)))
```

or if you want index:

```
def find_index(lst):
    min_len = 1e10
    min_idx = None
    for i, v in enumerate(your_list):
        curr_len = len(v[-1])
        if curr_len < min_len:
            min_len = curr_len
            min_idx = i
    return i
```

Comment: this is one of the fastest solutions